# Combo box entries are not showing on the frame

Tags: java

i have a problem with combo box.
my entry not showing on the drop down list for some reason. I tried with 2 methods and non of them are working. Combo box appearing in the frame, but it's empty. I don't see where is the problem, and compilation not returning any errors.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TemplatesList extends JComboBox<String>
{
    public JComboBox faceCombo;
    private String[] lista = {"change", "handover"};
    private JComboBox wyobr = new JComboBox();


    public TemplatesList()
    {
    /*
        faceCombo = new JComboBox();
        faceCombo.setEditable(false);
        faceCombo.addItem("change request");
        faceCombo.addItem("emergancy change request");
        faceCombo.addItem("problem request");
        faceCombo.addItem("problem handover");
        faceCombo.addItem("Major Incident handover");
 */
for (int i=0; i < lista.length; i++)
{
    wyobr.addItem(lista[i]);
}
    }
}`enter code here`
```

main class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JList;

public class ChoosingPage
{
static JFrame frame;
JLabel choose;

public ChoosingPage ()
{
    frame = new JFrame ("Primark's templates");
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setLocation(50,50);
   // frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);



    TemplatesList lista = new TemplatesList();
    frame.add(lista, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    new ChoosingPage();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you do not need to create another JComboBox, from within the JComboBox that you already have. You are **extending** a JComboBox, which means you have access to all of its methods.

For example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TemplatesList extends JComboBox<String>
{
    private String[] lista = {"change", "handover"};


    public TemplatesList()
    {
        super(); //call JComboBox's constructor. This is standard practice
        for (int i=0; i < lista.length; i++)
        {
            this.addItem(lista[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

#### please note

I added `super()` to your constructor. However, that isn't what is solving your problem. But, we wan't the JComboBox's constructor to be run as well.

Comment: @TomaszKostrzewski Please accept my answer if it works :)